# Connect to GlassFish server using HttpURLConnection in Android

Tags: android, glassfish, netbeans-7, httpurlconnection

I am developing an Android application that accesses a remote server using HttpURLConnection.

The server was (and still is) developed using NetBeans so, when testing the server on my local machine, I run it using NetBeans and the built-in GlassFish server.

I have tried to connect to the running server in Eclipse using HttpURLConnection giving localhost as the server (with the socket) but keep getting Connection Refused.

I can still access the local server from my browser with no problem but can't get to it from Eclipse.

The code also works when copnnecting to the actual remote server.

I am not sure where to go next.

Comment: Are you running in the emulator or on a device? Even if running on the emulator I think that localhost points to the emulator not your computer.  You'd need to connect to your computer's IP.

Comment: I am running on the emulator. I will try changing it to my own IP and see what happens.

Comment: Now I get "No route to host". Must be because of the Subnet Mask or something.

Comment: if i remember correctly, `10.0.2.2` is the IP Address you need for the app on the emulator to talk to your development machine. Yep. see http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html ("Network Address Space")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i remember correctly, `10.0.2.2` is the IP Address you need for the app on the emulator to talk to your development machine. Yep. see http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html ("Network Address Space")